# SQL string parsing, then sorting and ordering by blocks of dates

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

This sounds like a question that should be on an exam I took in college, but I assure you it's a real world problem I'm trying to solve...and I'm not really a SQL expert.

Let's say I sell cameras (fictional), and each camera has its own unique serial number in the [prefix]-[number] format.  We change the prefix when we change firmware or put a new computer chip in.  The cameras have a 3 year shelf MFG warranty, so we're trying to give a serial number to our distributors to say "Any camera with a serial number under J05-123456 is probably too old, send it back"

The problem is, we produce the cameras sequentially, but then 50 camera will sit on the shelf in our warehouse, and the shipping guys will go grab a random one and ship it, so they're sold semi-sequentially, BUT there can be big outliers where a couple units were set aside for months then later sold.

There are roughly 10 million serials.  Any good way to accomplish this?

```
Serial      |  Sale Date
J22-521253  |  7/2/12
J22-521254  |  6/28/12
J22-521255  |  6/28/12
J22-521256  |  7/1/12
J22-521257  |  6/22/12
J22-521258  |  7/4/12
J22-521259  |  7/1/12
J22-521260  |  6/27/12
J22-521261  |  6/25/12
J22-521262  |  6/20/12
J22-521263  |  8/30/12
J22-521264  |  6/30/12
J22-521265  |  6/30/12
Y7-542127   |  5/1/12
Y7-542128   |  4/18/12
Y7-542129   |  4/22/12
Y7-542130   |  1/10/12
```

Comment: For 10 million rows, there isn't going to be an efficient way to do this, sorry. Substring matching and data type conversions are going to lead to a 10 million row table scan no matter what tricks you play with CHARINDEX etc.

Comment: Might want to add a prefix column and add an index on it.  To get the prefix:

SELECT LEFT(Serial,CHARINDEX(Serial,'-')-1)

Comment: I am assuming you want to put the query into an app.  One way to accomplish this is to materialize the dataset as part of a nightly job to create a smaller table with just the prefix and first serial number under a certain range.  You could index on the prefix and it would be super fast.

Comment: I only run the query once a month or so.  And I'd think I could eliminate a bunch of the results by using the date, then parsing the string.  Doesn't need to be efficient at all...we would be OK if it took a day or two to run.

Comment: I think you need to explain what you're trying to achieve a bit better.  Are you wanting all of the units with a certain prefix in the serial number? The units with a certain sales date?

Answer (score 0):

I am interpreting the question as saying that you want the earliest serial number still under warranty for each prefix.  Anything older would be too old.

Please clarify the question if this is not the case.

```
select prefix, salesdate, serial
from (select left(serial, 3) as prefix,
             row_number() over (partition by prefix order by salesdate) as seqnum
      from (select t.*, left(serial, 3) as prefix
            from t
            where datediff(days, salesdate, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) < 3*365.25
           ) t
    ) t
```

This uses row_number() to find the earliest serial still under warranty.